# Does a ball resting on the ground have acceleration?

Tags: gravity, acceleration, terminology

Does a ball resting on the Earth's ground have acceleration caused by gravity?

Comment: By acceleration, do you mean *proper* or *coordinate* acceleration?

Comment: I mean in the axis pointing to the center of the earth

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  See:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration

Comment: So the value of the balls acceleration is 1g?

Comment: Relative to what? Relative to the floor the ball is at rest.

Comment: Let me rephrase that. The force of the floor on the ball suggests that the floor is accelerating upward at 1g.

Comment: OK I don't understand anything.when I placed my mobile phone on the ground, its accelerometer shows nine point something m/s^2. So is that the value of its acceleration?

Comment: That's the engineer's choice of sign for the acceleration which is based on the false assumption that the floor is an inertial system. The real inertial system would be the phone in free fall. A phone in free fall does, of course, not experience any acceleration. That leaves us with measuring the acceleration of the floor, which would be pointing upward.

Comment: @CuriousOne - But Chris said that the mobile phone measured 9.something m/s^2 when "placed" on the ground (i.e. at rest relative to the ground), so that means it's *not* treating the floor as an inertial system, but rather measuring the proper acceleration of the floor, which is of course 9.8 m/s^2.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: I know, but trust me when I say that the engineer who made that sign convention THOUGHT, that he was measuring the acceleration of the phone in the coordinates of the floor and not that of the floor in the coordinates of the phone. And I think that's what most people will think, too and what is so confusing about the fact that we aren't living in an inertial system... at least those of us who aren't falling off tall buildings all the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> OK I don't understand anything.when I placed my mobile phone on the
>   ground, its accelerometer shows nine point something m/s^2. So is that
>   the value of its acceleration?

That is the value of the phone's *proper* acceleration.  From the Wikipedia article "[Proper acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration)":

> proper acceleration is the physical acceleration (i.e., **measurable
>   acceleration as by an accelerometer**) experienced by an object.

In the (non-inertial) coordinate system of the ground, the phone has no *coordinate* acceleration.

The proper acceleration of the phone is not due to gravity but, rather, the fact that the ground is preventing the phone from falling freely towards the center of the Earth.  That is to say, the phone has an accelerated world line.

In summary, the phone has a proper acceleration of $g$ and a coordinate acceleration, in the coordinate system of the ground, of zero.

Comment: Ok. With my friend we had a bet. I said that when a marble is at the floor the value of its acceleration is equal to g. He said that this value is 0 because we cannot see any change in the value of speed (constantly 0). Who won the bet?

Comment: You both won and you both lost? One is simply living in inertial land and the other one isn't. The observer in inertial land will say that the ball is accelerating. The one in non-inertial land will say that the ball is standing still. So you are living in inertial land and your friend likes non-inertial land better, I guess.

Comment: @ChrisMitsis One thing about the word "Proper" in contexts like these: I always found the terminology a bit weird until I lived in France, when I found that that one of the main meanings of the adjective "propre" is "intrinsic" or "its own". So I'm guessing that this meaning (which seems only to arise in English in this kind of scientific setting) came from mediaeval latin in scientific communications, and I always find it helpful to recall the etymology when I hear things like "proper velocity of galaxies" and so forth. It means something that can be measured within the thing's own being, ...

Comment: @ChrisMitsis ... without reference to other, outside "not-its-own" things. So a proper acceleration is what something carrying its own, self contained instruments can *measure*.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance - I agree that 'proper' normally means intrinsic as with proper time and proper acceleration, both of which can be measured by devices carried by the object without reference to any particular choice of reference frame. But 'proper velocity' has always seemed to me like an unfortunate choice of terminology, since it *does* depend on a choice of reference frame and thus is not 'intrinsic' in the same way, being defined as (distance traveled in the chosen frame)/(proper time).

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance: Thank you for clarifying the meaning, via the etymology, of the term "proper". That makes understanding some concepts so much easier!

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance: Some may also find it helpful to note the relationship with "property". "Proper acceleration" is a property of the object itself, in that an observer on the object can determine its proper acceleration without reference to anything else, whereas any other acceleration is measured relative to something else, and is therefore not a property of just the object.